# How to optimize this method(Find an item with two searches)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have that Object with two lists inside.

```
const list = {
    Operator: [
      {
        Login: 'login1',
        PermissionGroup: '2',
        Sub: '3',
      },
      {
        Login: 'login2',
        PermissionGroup: '3',
        Sub: '2',
      },
    ],
    PermissionGroups: [
      {
        PermissionGroupId: '2',
        GroupsName: 'Gestor',
        PermissionLevel: 2,
      },
      {
        PermissionGroupId: '3',
        GroupsName: 'Lider',
        PermissionLevel: 3,
      },
    ],
  };
```

In my redux, i have the "Sub" of the Operators. So what do I have to do...

Step 1: Get my Redux "sub" and find which Operator it is in

Step 2: Now that I have the Operator, I need to find which operator corresponds to the PermissionGroup, using the PermissioninGroup(into Operators) and the PermissionGroupId(into PermissionGroups)

This method does what I want (Ignore final return), How do I optimize this method? I didn't want to use two filters for this

```
const search = (sub) => {
    const usuario = listaUsuarios.filter((element) => element.Sub === sub)[0];

    const permissaoUsuario = listaPermissoes.filter(
      (element) => element.PermissionGroupId === usuario.PermissionGroup
    )[0];

    return permissaoUsuario.PermissionLevel;
  };
```

Comment: if there is only 1 use find instead of filter.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, the current solution seems okay (of course, if it is confirmed that one only requires the 0-th element from `.filter()`, it may be preferrable to use `.find()` instead). Since OP has requested an alternate, the solution below (which is not my recommendation) may achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const searchSub = (needle, {Operator, PermissionGroups}) => (
  [...Operator, ...PermissionGroups].reduce(
    (res, obj) => ({
      ...res,
      ...(
        'Sub' in obj && obj.Sub === needle
        ? {foundSub: {...obj}}
        : 'PermissionGroup' in res.foundSub &&
          'PermissionGroupId' in obj &&
          obj.PermissionGroupId === res.foundSub.PermissionGroup
          ? {matchedPermissionGroup: {...obj}}
          : {}
      )
    }),
    {foundSub: {}, matchedPermissionGroup: {}}
  )
);

const list = {
  'Operator': [{
      'Login': 'login1',
      'PermissionGroup': '2',
      'Sub': '3',
    },
    {
      'Login': 'login2',
      'PermissionGroup': '3',
      'Sub': '2',
    }
  ],
  'PermissionGroups': [{
      'PermissionGroupId': '2',
      'GroupsName': 'Gestor',
      'PermissionLevel': 2,
    },
    {
      'PermissionGroupId': '3',
      'GroupsName': 'Lider',
      'PermissionLevel': 3,
    },
  ]
};

console.log(searchSub('2', list))
console.log(
  'PermissionLevel: ',
  searchSub('2', list)?.matchedPermissionGroup.PermissionLevel
);
```

**Explanation**

- Use `...` spread operator to construct one array with elements from both `Operator` and `PermissionGroups` array
- Use `.reduce()` to iterate over this combined array
- When a `Sub` is found, track it in `res` object
- When a matching `PermissionGroupId` is found, track that as well
- The resulting `res` object will have elements from both `Operator` and `PermissionGroups` array that matched.

**NOTE**

- Just to reiterate, it is actually simpler to just use two separate `.find()` in this context.